# Query Data In Notary Node and Query Transaction in Normal Node

Tags: corda

I have a question about query data:

Is there any way to query all data stored by Notary Node and how to query transactions in other Node in Corda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Corda, each node is backed by its own database. This database only stores transactions that the node is aware of.

For privacy reasons, a node cannot query other nodes' databases. Instead, you'd have to write a flow that makes the other node query its database for you and send back the results. However, the other node would have control over what data is shared, if any.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how to query the sets of transaction in Normal Node?