# Querying Notary node

Tags: corda

This is with reference to the question "[Query Data In Notary Node and Query Transaction in Normal Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51531279/query-data-in-notary-node-and-query-transaction-in-normal-node/51534197#51534197)"

In the above link, only querying normal node has been answered.  However, I need to know, how to query the notary node ?

Answer (score 1):

Notary does not know the concept of a cordapp. Hence, all your flow query will not work on a notary node.

All of the crash shell methods so still work in the Notart node shell, but again, since it does not know what a state is, you cannot really query anything from the shell neither.

Comment: Is it still the same, that we can't see any data of a Notary Node by any means ? (For learning purposes in development localhost environment.)